# i'm making face attendance system using pyqt5 that writes attendance multiple times even when the person is logged in

Tags: python

I'm following a Youtube tutorial of making face recognition attendance system which writes the name and time in a csv file, when i try to run it writes the name of the person many times on the attendance sheet.
i tried using logic to avoid writing the name multiple times but now it won't write the name of the person more than one time even if i start it again.
the camera is kinda slow, could it be the computer or is it the code.

```
    def face_rec_(self, frame, encode_list_known, class_names):

    def mark_attendance(ID):
        """
        :taking attendance
        """
        self.already_in_file = set()
        date_time_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y/%m/%d, %H:%M")
        with open('Attendance1.csv',"r") as f:
            for line in f:
                self.already_in_file.add(line.split(",")[0])
        if ID and date_time_string not in self.already_in_file:
            with open ("Attendance1.csv", "a") as f:
                f.writelines(f'\n{ID},{date_time_string}')
```

Comment: i don't think the problem is coming from the Date_time_String, anyways i tried it but wont work

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend modifying the `date_time_string` in the `if` block - it seems to me that that is the problem. The `if` block checks if that exact time is in the file, but time changes over time, as we know.

Lemme put it in code as well, just so my answer isn't too short!

```
    def face_rec_(self, frame, encode_list_known, class_names):

    def mark_attendance(ID):
        """
        :taking attendance
        """
        self.already_in_file = set()
        #this at a minimum, but I believe it'll make the same mistake next hour
        date_time_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y/%m/%d, %H")
        #alternatively, use the one below
        #date_time_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y/%m/%d")
        with open('Attendance1.csv',"r") as f:
            for line in f:
                self.already_in_file.add(line.split(",")[0])
        if ID and date_time_string not in self.already_in_file:
            with open ("Attendance1.csv", "a") as f:
                f.writelines(f'\n{ID},{date_time_string}')
```

Comment: Edit - you had commented on my answer but then deleted the comments? Anyway, verify that `line.split(",")[0]` and `ID` indeed do carry the same data. Maybe you have some whitespace you haven't `.strip()`ed off. Other than that, I am not sure.

Comment: sorry about the comment i deleted i am new here i though i placed it at the wrong place so i deleted it. from the tutorial i was following the guy did not use logic the code worked just fine for him, could it be my computer is slow

Comment: if it helps the tutorial i'm followin is on youtube channel named **AugmentedStartups**.